# How to get all buckets of last 24hrs in date histogram in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, date-histogram

I am using Date Histogram with Minimum interval as Hourly to get the results of Last 24 Hours and getting below graph. (v is 7.4)

[image]

The request is ,

```
GET access*/_search?pretty=true
{
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "1h",
        "time_zone": "Asia/Calcutta",
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "format": "k"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "stored_fields": [
    "*"
  ],
  "docvalue_fields": [
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "format": "date_time"
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "Request_URI": {
              "query": "\"/isp/v1/*\""
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time",
              "gte": "now-24h",
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}
```

In the curl response, i am getting below

```
"buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "9",
          "key" : 1627270200000,
          "doc_count" : 44
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "10",
          "key" : 1627273800000,
          "doc_count" : 51
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "11",
          "key" : 1627277400000,
          "doc_count" : 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "12",
          "key" : 1627281000000,
          "doc_count" : 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "13",
          "key" : 1627284600000,
          "doc_count" : 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "14",
          "key" : 1627288200000,
          "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "15",
          "key" : 1627291800000,
          "doc_count" : 16
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "16",
          "key" : 1627295400000,
          "doc_count" : 57
        }
```

Although for last 24h, data first start coming at 9AM but why it's not returning all buckets before 9AM if i am using now-24h .i.e its not showing all last 24 buckets. How can i get that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`extended_bounds`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation-extended-bounds) in order to make sure to get the first buckets which contain no documents:

```
  "date_histogram": {
    "field": "@timestamp",
    "calendar_interval": "1h",
    "time_zone": "Asia/Calcutta",
    "min_doc_count": 0,
    "format": "k",
    "extended_bounds": {
      "min": "now-24h",
      "max": "now"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Val, Its working.. I was in fact expecting reply from you.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help :-)